# bootstrap datepicker is hidden in modal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, datepicker

User needs to pick up date from modal dialog. Everything works perfectly except I don't see date picker dialog (it seems that is shrinked or something like that) Here's how it looks
[image]

I also try to add z-index to my css file but this also didn't worked for me

```
.date {
    z-index: 999999999;
}
```

So here's my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{{ asset('css/customstyles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src={{ asset('js/page_scripts.js') }}></script>
        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @yield('navbar')
        @yield('content')
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.date').datepicker({
                format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my modal where this problem occurs

```
<div id="add-medicine" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            {{ Form::open(array('class'=>'form-horizontal', 'onsubmit' => 'return false')) }}
            <div class="modal-header" >
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Prdėti medikamentą</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('filldate', 'Data', array('class' => 'control-label col-sm-3')) }}
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="input-group date">

                            {{ Form::text('text', null, array('class' => 'date form-control filldate', 'required'=> '')) }}
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('expiredate', 'Galioja iki', array('class' => 'control-label col-sm-3')) }}
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="input-group date">

                            {{ Form::text('text', '', array('class' => 'date form-control expiredate', 'required'=> '')) }}
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                {{Form::submit('Išsaugoti', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block js-save-new-animal', null))}}
            </div>
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So any ideas what I'm missing and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Very hard to debug without the fully rendered HTML and CSS. It doesn't look like a z-index issue. It looks more like the datepicker has no contents in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so finally I found the solution. It seems that `1.5.0` version has some bugs so I just need to replace to `1.7.1` version and now it works perfectly.